# Regex replace non letters with '-', but leave any periods

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to strip all non letters from a file path, but I need to leave the extension at the end.

File example:
`$text = cat.jpg`

I am current using this `$text = preg_replace('/[^\\pL\d]+/u', '-', $text);`
Result: `cat-jpg`

But this also converts any periods to a hyphen as well, I looked around and tried what I found from other posts, but they just removed the period all together.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: How should `cat.super-fluffy2.jpg.b_ak` turn out?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Tricky, but probably this: cat-super-fluffy2-jpg.b-ak

Comment: Are you sure? That does not match the description in your title nor question body and the accepted answer would fail to meet your expectation.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I edited reply, accepted answer is suitable, not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex based on alternation and negative lookahead for your search:

```
[^\pL\pN.]+|\.(?![^.]+$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qP5qG8/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
[^\pL\pN.]+  # Search 1 or more of any char that is not DOT and letter and number (unicode)
|            # OR
\.           # search for DOT
(?![^.]+$)   # negative lookahead to skip DOT that is just before file extension
```

In PHP code:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^\pL\pN.]+|\.(?![^.]+$)/u', '-', $text);
```